# Push View Controllers from Modal View in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, segue

I am using storyboard and have a screen which is presented modally, which I then need to push other view controllers from so that I can select items for the modal view (similar to adding an entry on the iPhone Calendar app). So I am going from:

Navigation Controller > VC > Modal View Controller > ??? Here I want to push a VC so that I can select an item to return to the modal view.

How can I make this possible as I'm currently getting an error "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

Ah ok, so I now have it setup like you said, I now get an error when trying to set a property on the view controller (I was using a push controller before) using the following:

```
SetTransactionDateViewController *stdvc = (SetTransactionDateViewController *)[segue destinationViewController]; 
// Get the day to pass to the select date controller
stdvc.transactionDate = [Utilities convertStringToDate:cellDate.detailTextLabel.text:FORMAT_DD_MMM_YYYY];
```

"[UINavigationController setTransactionDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: That "unrecognized selector" is a different question and not related to StoryBoard. Please create a new question (and accept jsksma2's answer as the correct one, if it helped you to solve the original question)

Comment: Btw the unrecognized error means that property transactionDate is not visible in SetTransactionDateViewController class header... so it's kind of StoryBoard related after all.

Comment: Your secondary error "[UINavigationController setTransactionDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"....You are trying to set the transaction date on the navigation controller that is presented modally. You need to dig deeper into the navigation controller to get the actual transactiondateviewcontroller out before setting the transaction date ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you allocate the view that you are presenting modally, you need to make sure that this view is embed inside of a `UINavigationViewController`. Navigation Controllers are required in order for you to do segues like the one you described.

Your storyboard should look like so:
[image]

Comment: The modal view is already in a Navigation Controller (I've edited the above).

Comment: Well the error that you're getting is stating the latter. Every time you use a modal segue and want to perform more segues, you need a `UINavigationViewController`.

Comment: Thanks, I now get an error when trying to set a value on the view controller (edited original question)

Comment: You haven't properly set the delegate of the select view controller, so it doesn't know what to setTransactionDate is supposed to set to. Although, that is something you need to inquire about in another question. As far as this one goes, it appears as though I've answered it.