# Moving from one view to another iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm relatively new to iOS development. I am to move from one viewController to another I use a modal segue transition on button click. This is a game so i want to allow the user to click images to essential move the the app menus.

I have a main page that displays several images, on clicking one i want to be able to move to another view. Currently doing this with a modal segue is causing odd problems with my touchesEnded event where if, for example, i navigate to a page 3 times the touchesEnded event is fired 3 times.

Is there a better way for me to do this or am i just missing thing fundamental?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you must make the the navigation controller your root view controller then push views accordingly

```
UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:YOUR_BASE_CONTROLLER]
self.rootViewController = nav;
```

this is in your app delegate.

Then in your action method

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES]
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have fixed the touchedEnded event being fired all the time. However, i did not put any code if the appDelegate as I'm not sure where to put it. Instead i attached a NavigationControoler onto my main View controller, is that the same thing?

Comment: you can add it in the app did finished launching with options function in app delegate. But if your current implementation works then keep it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you are using the Storyboard to link VCs using segues.

Modal segues are great for simple transitions but really seem to limit what you can accomplish when they are just linked through SB.  Ive found that creating an IBAction that includes the following for a VC segue will allow you to not only control your segues more efficiently but also allow you to have a clearer view of what is actually occurring during the transition.

```
-(IBAction)goToVc:(id)sender{
    //Other code to take place during the segue here

    //This will identify the Storyboard in use
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"   bundle:nil];

    //This will identify the View Controller to switch to
    SecondViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerID" ];

    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: *"Currently doing this with a modal segue is causing odd problems with my touchesEnded event where if, for example, i navigate to a page 3 times the touchesEnded event is fired 3 times."*

When I implement it this way, i still get the behaviour mentioned above

Comment: Thanks for good hint Dana K, your example worked perfectly in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you perform a modal segue, you lose the `UINavigationController` that you were previously using. What you need to do is embed a `UINavigationController` in the view that you are performing a modal segue to.

Check out a [question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222810/push-view-controllers-from-modal-view-in-storyboard/14222884#14222884) the other day to help you visualize more clearly what I'm talking about.